# Is it possible to setup/emulate a special Windows printer driver for ActiveX elements in IE ob Wine?

Tags: wine, ie, printing

I have a Zebra TLP thermal printer (LPT-attached) and a proprietary business web application using  an ActiveX element to print on it. Is there a way to make it work on Linux?

If there was, then I could probably extinguish Windows in my company!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the web application, your best bet is to try running Internet Explorer in Wine using the method here: http://yokozar.org/blog/archives/236

Wine prints using ordinary Linux printing system (cups), so you'll need to get the printer working "normally" as well.  However if I'm reading your post right it seems like the printer requires a special Windows driver.  If the printer doesn't just work, you may be in for some difficulty, however all may not be lost.

http://wiki.winehq.org/Printing  mentions a project to get Windows Printer drivers to work via Wine; this morphed into the ddiwrapper project.  ddiwrapper has the potential to make Windows XP printer drivers work in Ubuntu, however it is not packaged for Ubuntu at this point and I am unsure of the project's current state (it started as a Novell thing some years ago).